# Read File Content Line by Line from byte[] in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy

I have a byte[], What I need to do is, to read the content line by line. In Java We can get this by converting it to BufferedReader. But how to do it using Groovy Script?

Comment: You say _"Read File Content"_ in the title, but then make no reference to a File in the question...  What is it you are trying to do exactly?  Does my answer cover it?

Comment: Yes,You gave me the expected result. Really Thanks for the support. Could you please tell me about second method i.e "def input = '''|A small ae: æ
               |And an o with stroke: ø'''.stripMargin()"

Comment: `stripMargin` [just makes multi-line text](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#stripMargin%28%29) look nicer in source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the power of the [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/):

```
new ByteArrayInputStream( arr ).eachLine('UTF-8') { line ->
    println line
}
```

Note: If you need a 1:1 mapping between bytes and characters (for example when processing binary data), use `iso-8859-1` as encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this (checking encoding works):

```
def input = '''|A small ae: æ
               |And an o with stroke: ø'''.stripMargin()

println "Input is:"
println input

// Get the bytes for the input
byte[] arr = input.getBytes( 'UTF-8' )
```

then, to read each line of this byte array, you just need to do:

```
println "Output is:"
new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayInputStream( arr ), 'UTF-8' ).with {
  eachLine { line ->
    println line
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for proper use of encoding. I'd like to suggest to avoid the simple example at the beginning in the future - the encoding should always be supplied. If you need a 1:1 mapping, use `iso-8859-1`

Comment: Also note that you can use `new ByteArrayInputStream( arr ).eachLine('UTF-8') { line -> println line }`

Comment: @AaronDigulla Nice alternative!  If you post that as an answer, I'll vote it up, as it is nicer than my suggestions.  Struck out my first bit of code as well, as I agree...  Ignoring encoding is a route to failure...