# Java - reading file as binary with readLine

Tags: java, ruby, file, groovy

I have a Ruby code that reads file line-by-line and checks if it needs to read the next line to some block or it should handle that block and continue reading file parsing each line.

Here's it:

```
File.open(ARGV[0], 'rb') do |f|
    fl = false
    text = ''

    f.readlines.each do |line|
        if (line =~ /^end_block/)
            fl = false

            # parse text variable
        end

        text += line if fl == true

        if (line =~ /^start_block/)
            fl = true
        end
    end
end
```

E.g. i need the file to be opened for reading as binary and still i need a `readLine` method.

**So, the question is:** how can i do *exactly the same* with Groovy/Java?

Comment: @fge sorry, did not understand your question...

Comment: You seem to be reading text, hence the question. Is it simply because you open the file with `rb`?

Comment: Does this preserve the original new lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.io.DataInputStream` which provides both a `readLine()` method and `readFully(byte[])` and `read(byte[])` methods.

**Warning**: The JavaDoc for `readLine` says, it is deprecated and that the encoding might be inappropriate (read details in JavaDoc).

So think twice about your real requirements and if this is a suitable trade-off in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have line formatted text, that's not binary IMHO.  That's because true binary can have any byte, even `new line` and `carriage return` which would create false breaks in the code.

What you could mean is you have text where you want to read each byte without encoding or possibly mangling them.  This is the same as using `ISO-8859-1`.

You can try

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(filename), "ISO-8859-1"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
boolean include = false;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("end_block"))
        include = false;
    else if (line.startsWith("start_block"))
        include = true;
    else if (include)
        sb.append(line).append('\n'); // new lines back in.
}
br.close();
String text = sb.toString();
```

Comment: well, i'm trying to invoke a Inflate on those text blocks. so, i need them to be binary. does not matter how i do this ( like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322615/read-file-content-line-by-line-from-byte-in-groovy ) i get the `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: unknown compression method` exception. so, i thought it may be caused by the wrong file reading format...

Comment: When you read a ZIPped file you first have to uncompress it.  You can do this in Java or on the command line first.  It doesn't just know to read a compressed file as uncompressed data. (I would be surprised if Ruby does this automatically for you)

Comment: Given your error message, are you sure its compressed with ZIP?

Comment: nope =) even more, i am sure it is not. i am trying to read a PDF file =)

Comment: To get a zip.DataFormatException you have to be using a library which is trying to read a ZIP file. e.g. ZIPInputStream. I don't suggest you do that.

Comment: It may be overkill, but have you considered using a PDF library like http://www.icepdf.org/

Comment: oh, no. for some reasons i am not able to use any libraries other than standard java ones. and yes, i use `java.util.zip.Inflater` class to decode PDF stream objects. Do you have any suggestions how can i inflate deflated data using standard Java classes? =) because Ruby uses `zlib` =)

Comment: Using Inflator/Deflator is relatively easy, but I have never tried to use it to decode a PDF.  Java uses `zlib` as well. I believe its an unrelated question to the one you originally asked.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks anyway. Gonna ask another one =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public final class Read
{
    private static final Pattern START_BLOCK = Pattern.compile("whatever");
    private static final Pattern END_BLOCK = Pattern.compile("whatever");

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Not enough arguments");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        final FileReader r = new FileReader(args[0]);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        boolean inBlock = false;

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (END_BLOCK.matcher(line).matches()) {
                inBlock = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (inBlock)
                sb.append(line);

            if (START_BLOCK.matcher(line).matches())
                inBlock = true;
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```