# Reading .rfe(game Source) file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a game source file, it has .rfe extension

It is read using the below code

```
try{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.rfe"));
    String line=null;

    while((line=br.readLine())!=0)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It reads whole file, but after the process I am getting continuous "Beep" sounds from my system and my System is not responding.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The reason you're getting a beeping is that you're trying to print to screen a binary file - no doubt it contains some bell characters.

Comment: Yes, it has bell characters and its a binary file and i am trying to find some strings from that file and i want to display it in a textarea

Comment: This might help you [Java - reading file as binary with readLine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614950/java-reading-file-as-binary-with-readline)